# gensim word2vec: Find number of words in vocabulary

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, gensim, word2vec

After training a word2vec model using python [gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html), how do you find the number of words in the model's vocabulary?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In recent versions, the `model.wv` property holds the words-and-vectors, and can itself can report a length – the number of words it contains. So if `w2v_model` is your `Word2Vec` (or `Doc2Vec` or `FastText`) model, it's enough to just do:

```py
vocab_len = len(w2v_model.wv)
```

If your model is just a raw set of word-vectors, like a `KeyedVectors` instance rather than a full `Word2Vec`/etc model, it's just:

```py
vocab_len = len(kv_model)
```

Other useful internals in Gensim 4.0+ include `model.wv.index_to_key`, a plain list of the key (word) in each index position, and `model.wv.key_to_index`, a plain dict mapping keys (words) to their index positions.

In pre-4.0 versions, the vocabulary was in the `vocab` field of the Word2Vec model's `wv` property, as a dictionary, with the keys being each token (word). So there it was just the usual Python for getting a dictionary's length:

```
len(w2v_model.wv.vocab)
```

In very-old gensim versions before 0.13 `vocab` appeared directly on the model. So way back then you would use `w2v_model.vocab` instead of `w2v_model.wv.vocab`.

But if you're still using anything from before Gensim 4.0, you should definitely upgrade! There are big memory & performance improvements, and the changes required in calling code are relatively small – some renamings & moves, covered in the [4.0 Migration Notes](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#4-vocab-dict-became-key_to_index-for-looking-up-a-keys-integer-index-or-get_vecattr-and-set_vecattr-for-other-per-key-attributes).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be valid for version 4

Comment: Indeed see the Gensim 4 migration notes: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#4-vocab-dict-became-key_to_index-for-looking-up-a-keys-integer-index-or-get_vecattr-and-set_vecattr-for-other-per-key-attributes

Comment: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0. Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.

Answer (score 8):

One more way to get the vocabulary size is from the embedding matrix itself as in:

```
In [33]: from gensim.models import Word2Vec

# load the pretrained model
In [34]: model = Word2Vec.load(pretrained_model)

# get the shape of embedding matrix    
In [35]: model.wv.vectors.shape
Out[35]: (662109, 300)

# `vocabulary_size` is just the number of rows (i.e. axis 0)
In [36]: model.wv.vectors.shape[0]
Out[36]: 662109
```

Answer (score 5):

Gojomo's answer raises an `AttributeError` for Gensim 4.0.0+.

For these versions, you can get the length of the vocabulary as follows:

`len(w2v_model.wv.index_to_key)`

(which is slightly faster than: `len(w2v_model.wv.key_to_index)`)

Answer (score 1):

AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0. as the error says we can go for **.key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list**

model = Word2Vec(text,min_count=1)

words=model.wv.**index_to_key**  `instead of vocab`

Here the number of words in a alphabetic order.
example:

a <- army,africa,agreement.  count of the words in a is 3

model.wv["a"]  to see the array/co-ordinates.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

**Latest:**

Use model.wv.key_to_index, after creating gensim model

vocab dict became key_to_index for looking up a key's integer index, or get_vecattr() and set_vecattr() for other per-key attributes:https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#4-vocab-dict-became-key_to_index-for-looking-up-a-keys-integer-index-or-get_vecattr-and-set_vecattr-for-other-per-key-attributes