# How to get vocabulary word count from gensim word2vec?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I am using gensim word2vec package in python. I know how to get the vocabulary from the trained model. But how to get the word count for each word in vocabulary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gensim word2vec: Find number of words in vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596031/gensim-word2vec-find-number-of-words-in-vocabulary)

Comment: Since gensim v4, you should consider change the accepted answer, @Makan provides a good update.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Each word in the vocabulary has an associated vocabulary object, which contains an index and a count.

```
vocab_obj = w2v.vocab["word"]
vocab_obj.count
```

Output for google news w2v model: 2998437

So to get the count for each word, you would iterate over all words and vocab objects in the vocabulary.

```
for word, vocab_obj in w2v.vocab.items():
  #Do something with vocab_obj.count
```

Comment: As of [`gensim` 1.0.0](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/releases/tag/1.0.0), you need to do `w2v.wv.vocab["word"].count` instead of `w2v.vocab["word"].count`.

Comment: Just to clarify, word count ≠ word frequency.

Comment: @aucamort would you explain a bit what do you mean by `word count ≠ word frequency`? This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55659539/6907424) seems to be counter-intuitive w.r.to what you have said.

Answer (score 11):

The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in [Gensim 4.0.0](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/releases/tag/4.0.0beta).

Instead:

```
word2vec_model.wv.get_vecattr("my-word", "count")  # returns count of "my-word"
len(word2vec_model.wv)  # returns size of the vocabulary
```

Check out notes on [migrating from Gensim 3.x to 4](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#4-vocab-dict-became-key_to_index-for-looking-up-a-keys-integer-index-or-get_vecattr-and-set_vecattr-for-other-per-key-attributes)

Comment: Upvoted, this how to do it since v4

Answer (score 5):

When you want to create a dictionary of word to count for easy retrieval later, you can do so as follows:

```
w2c = dict()
for item in model.wv.vocab:
    w2c[item]=model.wv.vocab[item].count
```

If you want to sort it to see the most frequent words in the model, you can also do that so:

```
w2cSorted=dict(sorted(w2c.items(), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True))
```