# how to acquire word frequency from Word2Vec model

Tags: python, word2vec

I have already trained a Word2Vec model with gensim.models.Word2Vec.
by which means can I acquire the frequency of each word in this model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get vocabulary word count from gensim word2vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190989/how-to-get-vocabulary-word-count-from-gensim-word2vec)

Comment: Why did you accept the answer? Those are not the real counts. Those counts are generated by gensim and they are the positions of words not their frequency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('Word2VecModel/word2vec')
 for w in model.vocab:
     print (w, model.vocab[w].count)
```

Comment: My model says I have 5,339 words. The count output for each word decreases by 1 from 5,339 to 1. `count` is a tracker, not the actual frequency.

Comment: @briennakh True. Mine starts with 3000000 and goes down 1 by 1. Cannot be true.