# gensim: Retrieving word frequency in doc2vec vocabulary

Tags: dictionary, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec, vocabulary

I just came across [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190989/how-to-get-vocabulary-word-count-from-gensim-word2vec) on word counts in a doc2vec model vocabulary. I wonder if there is another method to retrieve the word frequency, other than

```
for word, vocab_obj in model.wv.vocab.items():
    print(str(word) + str(vocab_obj.count))
```

Maybe there is a more elegant way via the gensim library (i.e. output words and frequencies in a txt file)?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that in-memory dictionary (`model.wv.vocab`) is where the counts are stored for consultation, and any other further choices for display/storage are up to the user's own code.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarification. Do your have examples of word-snippets that can help to sort and show the word count? In case, I would recommend this for a future gensim version. It might help to inspect the data and whether cleaning (i..e of outliers) worked as expected.

Comment: By default the words are given their indexes in the vector-array in decreasing frequency, so if you look at the list `model.wv.index2word`, the word-tokens will be in most-frequent to least-frequent order. Other than that, it'd depend on your specific need - it's pretty straightforward Python to check if a word is present, or sort by a count, etc. For example it's a 1-liner to change existing word-vectors dict to a standard Python `Counter` via a dict-comprehension: `counts = Counter({word: vocab.count for (word, vocab) in model.wv.vocab.items()` – which then has a `most_common()` function.