# How can I count word frequencies in Word2Vec's training model?

Tags: python, word2vec, word-embedding, word-frequency, nlp

I need to count the frequency of each word in `word2vec`'s training model. I want to have output that looks like this:

```
term    count
apple   123004
country 4432180
runs    620102
...
```

Is it possible to do that? How would I get that data out of word2vec?

Comment: Add what you have tried so far

Comment: have you tried collections.Counter ?
it takes an iterable and returns a dict with counted elements

Answer (score 2):

Which word2vec implementation are you using?

In the popular `gensim` library, after a `Word2Vec` model has its vocabulary established (either by doing its full training, or after `build_vocab()` has been called), the model's `wv` property contains a `KeyedVectors`-type object, which as a property `vocab` which is a dict of `Vocab`-type objects, which have a `count` property of the word's frequency in the scanned corpus.

So you could get roughly what you seek with something like:

```
w2v_model = Word2Vec(your_corpus, ...)
for word in w2v_model.wv.vocab:
    print((word, w2v_model.wv.vocab[word].count))
```

Plain sets of word-vectors (such as those loaded via `gensim`'s `load_word2vec_format()` method) won't have accurate counts, but are by convention usually internally ordered from most-frequent to least-frequent.