# Extract token frequencies from gensim model

Tags: python, gensim

Questions like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190989/how-to-get-vocabulary-word-count-from-gensim-word2vec) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657062/how-can-i-count-word-frequencies-in-word2vecs-training-model) give answers for retrieving vocabulary frequencies from gensim word2vec models.

For some reason, they actually just give a deprecating counter from n (size of vocab) to 0, alongside the most frequent tokens, ordered.

For example:

```
for idx, w in enumerate(model.vocab):
    print(idx, w, model.vocab[w].count)
```

Gives:

```
0 </s> 111051
1 . 111050
2 , 111049
3 the 111048
4 of 111047
...
111050 tokiwa 2
111051 muzorewa 1
```

Why is it doing this? How can I extract term frequencies from the model, given a word?

Comment: Shouldn't you write "model.wv.vocab"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those answers are correct for reading the declared token-counts out of a model which has them.

But in some cases, your model may only have been initialized with a fake, descending-by-1 count for each word. This is most likely, in using Gensim, if it was loaded from a source where either the counts weren't available, or weren't used.

In particular, if you created the model using `load_word2vec_format()`, that simple vectors-only format (whether `binary` or plain-text) inherently contains no word counts. But such words are almost always, by convention, sorted in most-frequent to least-frequent order.

So, Gensim has chosen, when frequencies are not present, to synthesize fake counts, with linearly descending int values, where the (first) most-frequent word begins with the count of all unique words, and the (last) least-frequent word has a count of 1.

(I'm not sure this is a good idea, but Gensim's been doing it for a while, and it ensures code relying on the per-token `count` won't break, and will preserve the original order, though obviously not the unknowable original true-proportions.)

In some cases, the original source of the file *may* have saved a separate `.vocab` file with the word-frequencies alongside the `word2vec_format` vectors. (In Google's original `word2vec.c` code release, this is the file generated by the optional `-save-vocab` flag. In Gensim's `.save_word2vec_format()` method, the optional `fvocab` parameter can be used to generate this side file.)

If so, that 'vocab' frequencies filename may be supplied, when you call `.load_word2vec_format()`, as the `fvocab` parameter - and then your vector-set will have true counts.

If you word-vectors were originally created in Gensim from a corpus giving actual frequencies, and were always saved/loaded using the Gensim native functions `.save()`/`.load()` which use an extended form of Python-pickling, then the original true `count` info will never have been lost.

If you've lost the original frequency data, but you know the data was from a real natural-language source, and you want a more realistic (but still faked) set of frequencies, an option could be to use the Zipfian distribution. (Real natural-language usage frequencies tend to roughly fit this 'tall head, long tail' distribution.) A formula for creating such more-realistic dummy counts is available in the answer:

[Gensim: Any chance to get word frequency in Word2Vec format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58735585/gensim-any-chance-to-get-word-frequency-in-word2vec-format/58737377#58737377)